# How to select specific child nodes, having particular attribute value, using the parent node object, using XML query in JScript?

Tags: xml, xpath, jscript

```
My XML:
     <tests>
     <test name="Machine1" enabled="true">
     <action enabled="true" Result="true">T_1</action>
     <action enabled="true" Result="false">T_2</action>
     <action enabled="true" Result="true">T_3</action>
     <action enabled="true" Result="none">T_4</action>
     </test>
     <test name="Machine2" enabled="false">
     <action enabled="true" Result="true">T_5</action>
     <action enabled="true" Result="false">T_6</action>
     <action enabled="true" Result="false">T_7</action>
     <action enabled="true" Result="true">T_8</action>
     </test>
     </tests>
```

I want to select child nodes having, attribute [@Result='true'] from the "test" node having attribute [@enabled='true']. 
i.e ideally it should give two nodes:

```
<action enabled="true" Result="true">T_1</action>
<action enabled="true" Result="true">T_3</action>
```

Instead I am getting all nodes from the entire xml having attribute [@Result='true']. i.e:

```
<action enabled="true" Result="true">T_1</action>
<action enabled="true" Result="true">T_3</action>
<action enabled="true" Result="true">T_5</action>
<action enabled="true" Result="true">T_8</action>
```

My Code:

```
var filepath = "C:\\Test.xml"
var oXML = Runner.CallMethod("XMLLib.LoadDOM", filepath);
var testNodes = oXML.SelectNodes("//test");
for (var i=0; i<testNodes.length; i++)
    {
     var test = testNodes.nextNode;
     if (test.getAttribute("enabled") == "true")
        {
        var pass = test.SelectNodes("//action[@Result='true']").length;
        var fail = test.SelectNodes("//action[@Result='false']").length;
        var missing = test.SelectNodes("//action[@Result='none']").length;
        }
    }
```

Please help me with the solution Or any other way to get the desired result...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake when trying to execute relative XPath that begin with `/` or `//`. You need to put a single dot (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath to make it relative to current context element, which is the element referenced by variable `test` :

```
var pass = test.SelectNodes(".//action[@Result='true']").length;
```

To get direct child element you can use `./child::action` instead, or simply `./action` or even just `action`. The simpler forms are possible because `child::` is the default axis in XPath. It will be chosen for use when you don't explicitly mention any other axis :

```
var pass = test.SelectNodes("action[@Result='true']").length;
```

Comment: I tried using                                                                                                var pass = test.SelectNodes("./child::action[@Result='true']").length;  and    var pass = test.SelectNodes(".//action[@Result='true']").length;                getting 'pass = 0'

Comment: So seems "." is not working. Or m I missing something in Syntax?

Comment: @Astral What is `action`'s attribute name actually, `ATPResult` or just `Result`?

Comment: @Astral I'm not familiar with JScript, but I suspect the problem was at this line : `var test = testNodes.nextNode;`. My answer assumed that `test` correctly reference current `<test>` element. Try using `foreach` loop instead, something like `foreach (test in testNodes){ ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead i tried modyfying the query as:

```
var name = test.getAttribute("name");
var testNode = "//test[@name=" + "'" + name + "'"; 
var pass = test.SelectNodes(testNode + "]/action[@Result='true']").length;
```

and i am getting the desired output.
Is it the correct/efficient way?